# Clipping UI strings without introducing ellipses (Firefox style sheets)

Tags: html, css, firefox, customization

When creating Firefox UI CSS style sheets, I sometimes want to reduce the number of characters shown for a UI element.  I want the element to be truncated at the width specified in the style sheet, without ellipses.  For some reason, getting rid of the ellipses seems almost impossible.

For example, in Firefox 50, there is a new `Whole Words` toggle button in the Find Bar.  Let's say we want that to just be `Whole`.

After trying appropriately specific CSS, I then tried the a more global scope in hopes it would work.  It didn't.  Here's the shotgun approach, which even with its overly aggressive scope, still fails:

```css
.findbar-entire-word, .findbar-entire-word * {
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
  width: 5em !important;
  text-overflow: clip !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

What needs to be adjusted in order to accomplish the goal of shortening the string while not adding any ellipses.

Comment: Those XUL elements may have attributes that override CSS styles. See [crop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/crop), for instance.

Comment: @MrLister Excellent point.  Any way to use CSS to override that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that good with XUL, but I'm afraid the answer is no. In the example, you could try hiding the entire content and then put `'Whole'` in the `::before` or `::after`.